# R: ggarange increasing distance between plot title of the muliplot and titles of each plot

Tags: r, plot

assume I've the following data to generate two barplot as a multiplot:

```
quarter1

    variable value merge1
1      h=4     3     no
2      h=7     2    yes
3      h=8     3     no
4     h=21     2     no

quarter2

   variable value merge2
1      h=6     1     no
2      h=7     2    yes
3     h=10     1     no
4     h=12     3     no
5     h=13     1     no
6     h=16     1     no
7     h=17     1     no
```

Code for the two plots:

```
bar_q <- ggplot(quarter1, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=merge1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
bar_qf <- bar_q  + ggtitle("k = 0") + 
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=24, color="gray0"), axis.title=element_blank()) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks= function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1))))) + 
scale_fill_manual(values= grp_colors, guide=F) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=24))

bar2_q <- ggplot(quarter2, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=merge2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") 
bar2_qf <- bar2_q + ggtitle(expression(k %in% group("[", "1;4", "]"))) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=24 , color="gray0"), axis.title=element_blank()) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3), breaks=seq(3)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values= grp_colors, guide=F) +  
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=24))
```

Generating multiplot with:

```
plot_quarter <- egg::ggarrange(bar_qf,bar2_qf, ncol=2, top=textGrob("Quartalsdaten:Häufigkeiten", gp=gpar(fontsize=28,font=2)))
```

Resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

If you look at the "g" in the plot title it's a bit cutted. However I tried to increase the distance between the title of the multiplot and the titles of each plot but don't find a way to do it in "ggarange". Do someone know how I can do this in ggarange/textGrob

Comment: try adding `padding=unit(1, "line")`

Answer (score 2):

grid has always been a bit peculiar in estimating textGrob heights. ggplot2 recently introduced a titleGrob to deal with this more consistently; unfortunately it's a private function not meant to be used externally.

The two easiest workarounds I can think of are:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- p2 <- ggplot()

library(grid)
# create a new class and give it a more generous height
tg <- grobTree(textGrob("Quartalsdaten:Häufigkeiten", gp=gpar(fontsize=28,font=2)), cl='title')
heightDetails.title <- function(x) grobHeight(x$children[[1]]) + unit(2,"line")
egg::ggarrange(p1,p2, ncol=2, top=tg)


library(gridExtra)
# wrap the text in a dummy gtable
tg <- gridExtra::tableGrob("Quartalsdaten:Häufigkeiten", 
                           theme = ttheme_minimal(base_size = 28, padding = unit(c(0, 2), "line"),
                                                  core = list(fg_params=list(font=2))))
egg::ggarrange(p1,p2, ncol=2, top=tg)
```

Edit: actually, as pointed out in the comments, ggarrange has a padding argument for this purpose,

```
egg::ggarrange(p1,p2, ncol=2, top=textGrob("Quartalsdaten:Häufigkeiten", gp=gpar(fontsize=28,font=2)), padding = unit(1,"line"))
```